# Excel VBA correct code for selecting visible rows/the active table?

Tags: excel, vba, select, range, autofilter

Morning all,

I've created VBA code to automate a very manual process of parsing data from one worksheet into several other work sheets for onward saving as individual .CSV files. The macro works great and I've even sorted a macro to save each individual worksheet as a .CSV into a folder so productivity wise it's looking very good!

My question comes around selecting the contents of the active table of data subject to an autofilter. For example, I have a large amount of data in this worksheet spanning to row 851079, I apply some filters which shows rows up to 29369. This part of the code shows it uses absolute references:

```
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$851079").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="EE"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$851079").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="2G"
    Range("A1:Q851079").Select
    Range("F29342").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This works for this workbook, but not every workbook I need the macro to run in will have exactly 851079 rows, it will have more/less but likely never the same.

My initial thoughts are rather 'agricultural' in that changing the range to the very last row in the worksheet (1048576). The number of columns will always be the same.

But is there a smarter way?

Comment: You can start by using the search feature on Upwork, you'll get this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/find-last-used-cell-in-excel-vba/11169920#11169920

Comment: Find the last used row in a specific column, Use column where your data is, something like: 

LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

' Apply filters based on the dynamic range
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="EE"

Comment: You should also have a look at [how to avoid Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: @vbakim I like this, it seems to be working quite well. I want to test it with another workbook with more rows to confirm it's working.

One question though, the first part where you define how to work out the range:
`LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row`

Do I need to include this at every point in the entire macro when referencing the range and select? 

Currently, I've only used it at the start and use the below where needed:
`ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$Q$" & LastRow).AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="2G"`
and
`Range("$A$1:$Q$" & LastRow).Select`

Comment: After you set your filter, you can try selecting only the visible cells:
ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells